# Bandwidth Reporter

Tags: c#

My company is cheap but wanted a way to pinpoint bandwidth on certain computers.  Me being a programming guy came up with the following small program.  I just wanted some expert opinion on my code.  I am especially interested in you opinion on how I usually pull permanent variables.  I usually put these variables in a class and then call them from that class.  That will be the class called ProgReferences.  Be as brutal as you want. I want to improve.

**Main Service**

```
namespace YWIPSnitch
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        ProgReferences r = new ProgReferences();
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            MonitorBandwidth();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }

        private void SendRegister(string computerName, string username, char inOrOut)
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = r.getRegisterInsertSQL();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@computer_name", computerName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_type", inOrOut);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException)
            {
                ReestablishDatabaseConnection();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void MonitorBandwidth()
        {
            NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            while (true)
            {
                foreach (var ni in interfaces)
                {
                    long beginBR = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
                    long beginBS = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent;
                    DateTime beginTime = DateTime.Now;

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);

                    long endBR = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
                    long endBS = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent;
                    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

                    long receivedBytes = endBR - beginBR;
                    long sentBytes = endBS - beginBS;
                    double totalSeconds = (endTime - beginTime).TotalSeconds;

                    long bytesPerSecRec = receivedBytes / Convert.ToInt64(totalSeconds);
                    long bytesPerSecSent = sentBytes / Convert.ToInt64(totalSeconds);

                    InsertUsageData(bytesPerSecRec, bytesPerSecSent);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void InsertUsageData(long bytesPerSecRec, long bytesPerSecSent)
        {
            string computerName = Environment.MachineName;

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
            string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
            username = username.Replace("YS\\", string.Empty);

            decimal dblBytesPerSecSent = bytesPerSecSent / 1024m;
            decimal dblBytesPerSecRec = bytesPerSecRec / 1024m;

            conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = r.getBWUsageInsertSQL();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@computer_name", computerName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bytes_sent", dblBytesPerSecSent);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bytes_received", dblBytesPerSecRec);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            catch (MySqlException)
            {
                ReestablishDatabaseConnection();
            }
        }

        private void ReestablishDatabaseConnection()
        {
            bool broken = true;
            conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();

            while (broken)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    conn.Close();
                    broken = false;
                }
                catch (MySqlException)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProgReferences**

```
namespace YWIPSnitch
{
    public class ProgReferences
    {
        //Variable Declarations
        string sqlConnString = ("SERVER=computerName; DATABASE=ywbwrat; UID=UID; password=Password;");
        string registerInsertSQL = @"INSERT INTO `ywbwrat`.`register` (`computer_name`, `username`, `register_type`) VALUES (@computer_name, @username, @register_type)";
        string bwUsageInsertSQL = @"INSERT INTO `ywbwrat`.`bw_info` (`computer_name`, `username`, `bytes_sent`, `bytes_received`) VALUES (@computer_name, @username, @bytes_sent, @bytes_received);";
        string viewList = @"SHOW FULL TABLES IN ywbwrat WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';";

        //Return any values that are asked for
        public string getSQLConnString()
        {
            return sqlConnString;
        } 
        public string getRegisterInsertSQL()
        {
            return registerInsertSQL;
        }
        public string getBWUsageInsertSQL()
        {
            return bwUsageInsertSQL;
        }
        public string getViewList()
        {
            return viewList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this ? Does it successful run as a service ?

Comment: Yes, I currently have it on 5 computers.  I was a bit worried, since it runs forever, that it would hit a snag along the way.  I have developed other programs and had to restart them because they ran into a problem eventually.  But this one runs just fine.

Comment: just a couple of things: This is c# not java use autoproperties to expose getter and setter and if they're constant use the const keyboard in the declaration. A method GetSomething is preferred to a property only if it is expensive (require computation, IO or whatever)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection should also be inside of a `using` statement.

The way that I normally do it, I create the connection inside the `using` statement and not at a higher scope like you have done.  I understand the reason you did what you did here, but not sure that it is necessary because you are only reusing the connection inside of 2 methods. I think it makes more work, but this is my personal opinion.

Your first method that uses the connection looks like this:

> ```
> private void SendRegister(string computerName, string username, char inOrOut)
> {
>     conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();
>
>     try
>     {
>         conn.Open();
>         using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
>         {
>             cmd.CommandText = r.getRegisterInsertSQL();
>             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@computer_name", computerName);
>             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
>             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_type", inOrOut);
>
>             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>         }
>     }
>     catch (MySqlException)
>     {
>         ReestablishDatabaseConnection();
>     }
>
>     conn.Close();
> }
> ```

I would do it like this:

```
private void SendRegister(string computerName, string username, char inOrOut)
{

    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = r.getRegisterInsertSQL();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@computer_name", computerName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_type", inOrOut);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        {
            ReestablishDatabaseConnection();
        }
    }         
}
```

---

I was taking a look at your `ReestablishDatabaseConnection` method and was a bit confused.

The method name doesn't really reflect what you are doing here:

> ```
> private void ReestablishDatabaseConnection()
> {
>     bool broken = true;
>     conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();
>
>     while (broken)
>     {
>         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
>         try
>         {
>             conn.Open();
>             conn.Close();
>             broken = false;
>         }
>         catch (MySqlException)
>         {
>
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

In the first bit of code that I reviewed, your `catch` statement sends your code here and then the exception never bubbles up so that you can see what is happening; if you hit the wrong kind of exception, you will be sitting here for a very long time waiting for the code to "fix itself" and it never will because it will be stuck in the `while (broken)` loop

Get rid of this and let the exceptions bubble up, then fix them.  Or even better, you should log these exceptions so that you can find the exceptions somewhere and allow the service to continue running.  It looks like you already have a database location; I would just set up a table that you could insert these exceptions into, and then dump the table after a set period of time or have old records "*fall off the table*".

Comment: I don't agree.  I like the try catch for connection and add a Finally with a Close().

Comment: the original code doesn't actually close the initial connection, so it could be testing a second condition in the `ReestablishDatabaseConnection` without actually closing the first connection,  this will cause a leak. @Paparazzi  there is no Finally in the OP code, so that connection isn't closed in the event of an exception.

Comment: @Paparazzi, a Using block actually does a Try/Finally with a close in the Finally

Comment: I did not know a using had a Finally.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: [under remarks, the sentence immediately before the code block. (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @Paparazzi, it compiles to a try/finally, it is syntactic sugar for a Try/Finally. at least that is how I see it.

Comment: I know this might sound bad but my reason for using the ReestablishDatabaseConnection() was only to keep the service from error state if it lost connection to the network for any reason. Secrecy from the user was a thing I was told to keep in mind and I didn't want any errors popping up on their screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for the first suggestion.  I will use this far more often.

Comment: logging the exception is better than what you are doing, and you don't have to alert the user that you are logging this exception or that you want the application to try again, @DavidRichards .

Answer (score 1):

Conn.Close(); should be in a finally statement used in both uses of connection.
According to Malichi using calls dispose().

So you re-establish the connection in the catch and leave - I don't see the value.  You are catching an error and doing nothing.  The calling method is not even aware of the error.

You are not processing the error.  What if the db is up but the credentials are bad?   Not testing for a higher level error (e.g. network).

Why break after first interfaces?

Consider using a producer consumer so if the connection does go down (for a period of time) you can catch up.

Networking Performance Counters may be better for this and it may not.  Just something to look at.

Just a start with better exception handling
A producer consumer is just plain better and will have better exception options

```
private bool SendRegister(string computerName, string username, char inOrOut)
{
    conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();
    bool returnBool = true;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = r.getRegisterInsertSQL();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@computer_name", computerName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_type", inOrOut);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        ReestablishDatabaseConnection();  // limited number of tries 
        // maybe log the ex
        returnBool = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // maybe log the ex
        returnBool = false;
    }
    finally();
    {
        conn.Close();
        return returnBool;
    }
}
```

Comment: That method is only to keep the program out of error just in case the computer loses connection to the database/network for any reason. I couldn't think of a better way to do it.  The idea here is to try to open the connection.  On failure, it will go to the catch instead of continuing to the broken = false and breaking out of the loop.

Comment: I don't think that is a very good way.  You are not providing information to fix or deal with the problem.  If it loses network connection it might not even throw a MySqlException.

Comment: I tested it and that is the error it does throw oddly enough. I agree this lacks elegance (or thought).  I can come up with a different method overtime.  While I do that though, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: SQL will throw some network specific errors.  The point is a lot of errors could be missed.

Comment: Alrighty, I changed it to catch(Exception){} until I can find a better way of doing this.

Comment: No you should do both

Comment: lol, alright. I will.